# React setting state in asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I have the following asynchronous function being used to validate valid user credentials via a REST service;

```
async doesLoginExist(regCode) {
    if (loginCode.match(loginCodePattern)) {
      try {
        await LoginService.getUserByLoginCode();
        return {};
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.status === 404) {
          return {
            error: 'Your login code is not recognized.', success: null
          };
        }
        return {
          error: 'Service is temporarily unavailable.', success: null
        };
      }
    }
    return {};
  }
```

However, when I try to set some state within this function;

```
async doesLoginExist(regCode) {
    await this.setState({ canProceed: false });
    if (loginCode.match(loginCodePattern)) {
      try {
        await LoginService.getUserByLoginCode();
        await this.setState({ canProceed: true });
        return {};
      } catch (err) {
        if (err.status === 404) {
          return {
            error: 'Your login code is not recognized.', success: null
          };
        }
        return {
          error: 'Service is temporarily unavailable.', success: null
        };
      }
    }
    return {};
  }
```

it no longer seems to correctly return my {error, success} object to the caller, which ends up being used as validation messages displayed on screen.  Another minor problem is autoFocus on the text box input the login code is entered does not work either.

Is there some other way I should be setting state within this function?

Comment: why are you using await on this.setState?

Comment: Hmmm i guess that wasn't needed.  Same problem when i take it out however.

Comment: You haven't described the problem clear enough, what does "no longer seems to CORRECTLY return my {error, success} mean?

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure `doesLoginExist` bound properly to component's context. Cant say for sure due to lack of info, however it is very common problem. [Read more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)
   Example how to bind `doesLoginExist` itself - you have to do it explicitly in a constructor

   ```
   constructor() {
     super();
     this.doesLoginExist = this.doesLoginExist.bind(this);
   }

   async doesLoginExist() {
     this.setState({ canProceed: false });
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Optionally refactor by extracting `this.setState` calls from `doesLoginExist` - into another method,  it will increase re-usability of `doesLoginExist`

   ```
   handleSomethingHappened = () => {
     this.setState({ canProceed: false });
     const result = await doesLoginExist(regCode)
     this.setState({ canProceed: true });
   }
   ```

Cheers.